Server selection timeout with MongoDB and Docker in Digital Ocean App Platform
I'm experiencing an issue with MongoDB and Docker when deploying to Digital Ocean App Platform from Docker Hub.
Here is the error output from the console:
server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: Unknown, Servers: [{ Addr: mongo:27017, Type: Unknown, Last error: dial tcp: lookup mongo on 10.245.0.11:53: no such host }, ] } 

My docker-compose.yml looks like this:
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    container_name: app
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    environment:
      MONGO_URL: "mongodb://****:****@mongo:27017/db?authSource=admin&directConnection=true" 
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/data/db
    command: ["./app"]
    networks:
      - app-network

  mongo:
    image: mongo:6.0
    restart: always
    container_name: mongodb
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: *****
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: *****
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - /mnt/data/mongo_db_data:/data/db
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

In the Go code, I'm using:
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
defer cancel()

mongoURL := os.Getenv("MONGO_URL")

clientMongo, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI(mongoURL))
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

Any ideas on what could be causing this issue?
I expected the application to connect to MongoDB successfully, but instead, it throws a server selection timeout error. I tried using directConnection=true in the MongoDB connection string, as well as ensuring that the containers are on the same Docker network.

Based on the documentation and limitations of DigitalOcean’s App Platform, it seems that running a MongoDB instance in a container within App Platform may not be viable due to several constraints. App Platform doesn’t support persistent storage or VPC networking, which can lead to connectivity and data loss issues when hosting databases directly in containers.
Instead, I recommend using DigitalOcean's Managed Databases service for MongoDB. This managed option provides the necessary persistent storage and network configurations, making it a more suitable choice for database hosting than App Platform, especially for applications needing reliable data storage and availability.
https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/app-platform/details/limits/
